ESP32 protoboard wifi not working due to jumper wires?
I made a prototype board (pics below) with a ESP32-C3 board that has a ceramic antenna. I'm a beginner for hardware stuff, but I soldered everything and it works just fine. I then made a second one with the same wiring, same esp32 board, but the wifi just won't work. The esp board works fine when removed, just won't work when on top of my prototype board.
It won't connect to existing networks nor is the wifi visible to other devices when in AP mode.
Am I correct in assuming it's likely because of the mesh of wires just below the antenna, and I just got lucky with the first one for some weird reason? I can't really think of anything else. Esp's wifi will stop working even when just placed on top of the board, without any soldering...
If so, am I good if I move the wires somewhere else? The only good placement for the esp board is there with the antenna in the middle. I read somewhere that protoboards should be okay under the antennd
Here is the board. The antenna is just to the other side of the red line



I think your experiments already confirmed that the proximity of the prototype board near the radio module is the issue.  Did you check if there is any uninsulated metal on the bottom of the ESP board that could contact the bare metal of the proto board, or better yet try a piece of insulating tape between the two boards just in case.  Beyond that, the real question then is how much clearance around the module's antenna is needed to improve the situation?
The distance around an antenna where a nearby conductor will become an unwanted part of the antenna is the "near field" of the antenna, the size of which is roughly the wavelength of the RF being used.  2.4GHz wifi band has wavelength approximately 125mm and 5 GHz will be half that distance.  The impact will also depend on the size of the nearby conductor, where anything close to 1/4 wavelength would be very significant.  So clearly the protoboard and especially the header pins are well within this distance from the ceramic antenna.
My guess is that the nearby header pins (much longer than the through-hole pads) could be the issue.  Suggest you do some more experiments:

try rotating the ESP board by 90 degrees on the proto board so the ceramic antenna is further from the header pins.
try cutting off the redundant ground pins on the header that are closest to the ceramic antenna, and maybe reassigning closest signal pins.
try flipping the header pins to be inserted from the bottom of the proto board (solder onto the bend in the pins), and place a thick foam tape under the ESP module to increase physical separation.

